# JSON to CSS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, json

I'm working on a JSON to CSS converter in NodeJS, which takes a .json file and generates a .css file with its utility classes from it.

.json example

```
    }
        "breakpoints-map": {
            "default": "0",
            "sm": "only screen and (min-width: 508px)",
            "md": "only screen and (min-width: 768px)"
        },
        "bg-repeat-map": {
            "bg-repeat": "repeat",
            "bg-repeat-y": "repeat-y",
            "bg-no-repeat": "no-repeat",
            "bg-repeat-x": "repeat-x"
        },
        "bg-position-map": {
            "bg-pos-top": "top",
            "bg-pos-right-top": "top right",
            "bg-pos-right-center": "right",
            "bg-pos-right-bottom": "right bottom",
            "bg-pos-bottom": "bottom",
            "bg-pos-left-bottom": "left bottom",
            "bg-pos-left": "left",
            "bg-pos-left-top": "left top",
            "bg-pos-center": "center center"
        },
        "bg-attachment-map": {
            "bg-att-scroll": "scroll",
            "bg-att-fixed": "fixed"
        },
        "border-style-map": {
            "border-dotted": "dotted",
            "border-dashed": "dashed",
            "border-solid": "solid",
            "border-double": "double"
        }
    }
```

.js code

```
    module.exports = (fileName) => {
        let cssWriter = fs.createWriteStream('style.css', {
            flags: 'a'
        });

        fs.readFile(fileName, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                functions.logIt("The file cannot be found or is unreadable.", error);
            } else {
                try {
                    const dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
                    const breakpointMap = dataJson["breakpoints-map"]
                    delete dataJson["breakpoints-map"];
                    Object.entries(breakpointMap).forEach(([breakpointKey, breakpointValue]) => {
                        if (functions.isDefault(breakpointKey) == false) {
                            cssWriter.write("@media " + breakpointValue + " {\n");
                        }
                        Object.entries(dataJson).forEach(([mapKey, mapValues]) => {
                            let breakpoint = (functions.isDefault(breakpointKey) == true ? "" : breakpointKey + "\\:");
                            let property = functions.getProperty(mapKey);
                            Object.entries(mapValues).forEach(([classKey, classValue]) => {
                                cssWriter.write("." + breakpoint + classKey + "{ " + property + ": " + classValue + "}\n");
                            })
                        })
                        if (functions.isDefault(breakpointKey) == false) {
                            cssWriter.write("}\n");
                        }
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    functions.logIt("The file could not be parsed to JSON.", error);
                }
            }
            cssWriter.end();
        });
    };
```

The `isDefault` function just checks whether the given parameter is equal to "default", in order to not put a media query around it.

The `getProperty` function just links the right CSS property depending on the map name (width-map => width, bg-repeat-map => background-position).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Read the [tour] if you haven't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I see is that it's not obvious what the output is because there's too much auxiliary code that effectively obfuscates the logic.

- Offload some of the code into a function.
- Use template strings.

If the data amount isn't in multi-megabyte range I would write a single string to improve readability:

```
const dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
const breakpointMap = dataJson['breakpoints-map'];
delete dataJson['breakpoints-map'];

const entryToCss = ([mapKey, mapValues], breakpoint) => {
  const property = functions.getProperty(mapKey);
  return Object.entries(mapValues)
    .map(([k, v]) => `.${breakpoint}${k}{ ${property}: ${v}}\n`)
    .join('');
};

cssWriter.write(
  Object.entries(breakpointMap).map(([bpKey, bpVal]) => {
    const breakpoint = functions.isDefault(bpKey) ? `${bpKey}\\:` : '';
    return `${
      breakpoint ? `@media ${bpVal} {\n` : ''
    }${
      Object.entries(dataJson)
        .map(entry => entryToCss(entry, breakpoint))
        .join('')
    }${
      breakpoint ? '}\n' : ''
    }`;
  }).join('')
);
```